# Android NDK, c++ vector data type

Tags: android-ndk

```
float CalcDistance(vector<SoundInfo> &FeatA, vector<SoundInfo> &FeatB){
     do something here
}
```

If I have this c++ source code then how do I use this using JNI in Android?
I read a couple of tutorial to use NDK and got some basic idea but I am not sure what kinds of data structure has to be passed from Java to JNI for the type vector in c++
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by writing a Java equivalent of the `SoundInfo` type, if it a struct or class (unless it is a typedef for some integral type). It should carry enough data to construct a `SoundInfo`. For example the Java object can contain equivalents of all parameters of the `SoundInfo`'s constructor, and they can be accessed directly as fields to minimize the JNI code.

Then you can write two helper functions - one to convert a Java object to `SoundInfo`, and one to convert a Java `List<JSoundInfo>` to `vector<SoundInfo>`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to pass the object to(JNI)/from(Java) via a jobjectArray. You can either stuff the SoundInfo into a SoundInfo[] and send it directly as a jobjectArray or pass the object itself if you'd like to just use Get/Set methods it provides.

See the JNI docs for Get/SetObjectField(), GetObjectArrayElement(), etc.